# Dynamic Lookup Activity and split function ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to run a select * query for table having where clause as tablename.
The table name is coming from pipelinename, so want to use split function.
[image]

Comment: what is your pipeline name here?

Comment: For the SQL to be valid, you still need ' marks around the value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above picture, you are giving the query in SQL. Your expression is correct but give the query in **lookup activity query** to get the desired result.

My Example:

[image]

Here, `sample1` is my SQL table name and `pipeline_sample1` is my pipeline name. I have given the below sample expression.

`select * from @{split(pipeline().Pipeline,'_')[1]}`

**Result:**

[image]